# Complicated Join in Entity Framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have 3 tables in a database (picture below).  I am trying to join the tables so I can get all the related information from all the tables.  I am starting at DAT_Demo and I have been able to get all the records from DAT_Demo and ARC_Records,  but I cannot figure out how to also pull in all the DAT_OrderDoctors records associated with ARC_Records.  I have the following code that pulls the records I want but DAT_OrderDoctors is not available.  How can i do this?

Code so far:

```
IQueryable<DAT_Demo> query = _localContext.DAT_Demo
    .Include("ARC_Records")
    .Include("ARC_Immuno")
    .OrderBy(d => d.LastName)
    .Where(d => SqlFunctions.PatIndex(txtSearch.Text + "%", d.FirstName + " " + d.LastName) > 0)
    .Take(100);

demo = query.ToList();
```

[image]

Comment: Note my code works, but the ARC_Records objects do not contain the DAT_OrderDoctor records.

Comment: dont you just want another include? `.Include("ARC_Records.DAT_OrderDoctor")`

Comment: I did not know I could do that...  You just learned me up.  That worked great

Comment: posted as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are after a second level include

```
.Include("ARC_Records.DAT_OrderDoctor")
```

or

```
.Include(d=>d.ARC_Records.Secect(a=>a.DAT_OrderDoctor))
```

Comment: you are answer is so good. I've a doubt what happens if add .Include("DAT_OrderDoctor") like this?

Comment: @RameshMuthiah The way the syntax works is that it looks for a property on your current table and will populate the navigation property. In the case you are describing I expect you will get an error as `DAT_OrderDoctor` isnt a property on `DAT_Demo`